# The module does not show up under Settings > Extensions. -Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I uploaded an extension to the project from the shopware admin panel. The extension is active and I can set the configurations. The problem is the module doesn't show up under Settings > Extensions. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Like Alex said, the configuration options do not appear by default under `Settings -> Extensions` for any given plugin.

If you want to add something like this to your plugin, you're going to have to specify a [settings item](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-module#special-case-settings) in your JS module, looking like this

```
settingsItem: [{
    group: 'plugin',
    to: 'my.custom.route',
    icon: 'my-plugin-icon',
    name: 'my.custom.settings.title'
}]
```

Of course, you are going to need a page for `my.custom.route`.

A working example of both can be seen in the [module registration file](https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshPlatformAdminer/blob/master/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/frosh-adminer/index.js#L22) and [page registration file](https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshPlatformAdminer/blob/master/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/frosh-adminer/page/frosh-adminer-view/index.js) of the [FroshPlatformAdminer](https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshPlatformAdminer) plugin

Comment: For completeness: Shopware only fully registers a module if it provides at least one route or a `routeMiddleware`. Otherwise `settingsItem`, `navigation` and `extensionEntryRoute` have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know which module you are talking about.

Anyways, each module you install should appear under Extensions -> My Extensions and you can configure basic settings (those which [are added by the developer via config.xml](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-plugin-configuration)) in the extension list, `...`-menu and then "configuration". I assume think that is already working in your case.

If the module you installed did not add extended configuration capabilities, then it will not be visible under Settings -> Extensions - so this is completely normal and not an error.

If you are developing that module and need extended settings, you have to add them via a VueJS / javascript module. This works roughly the same as [adding pages anywhere else in the admin panel](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-module).